# Set Atom 1.0 editor background transparency

Tags: atom-editor

I have just installed Atom 1.0, under Linux Ubuntu.

I think understand that I can set the background transparency given the info from this page: https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/frameless-window.md#transparent-window

They suggest adding: 
    `var win = new BrowserWindow({ transparent: true, frame: false });`

But where ? I don't see similar entries in the preferences?

Comment: I'm reading this right now, https://atom.io/packages/editor-background seems like this might be an answer, I try not to just post random links and hope that they contain the answer, but I've been searching for this for a while and I think this is it. I'll come back and edit this answer when I get something more concrete out of the feature page :)